# C# CMD - Interaction on prompt

Tags: c#, cmd, openssl

Due to constant demands on generation of self-signed certificates, I started to develop a simple console program which could speed up the process. It takes some args, start a CMD process and use openssl in the generation.

One of the openssl commands takes some input about the Distinguished Name and another one the CA password. For those prompts I write a line on StandardInput stream with the idea that it could also send a Enter key stroke. For the first case it seems to work but the second prompt hangs and never receives it. How to solve this?

Command:

```
 openssl x509 -req -in {Domain}.csr -CA {PathCA} -CAkey {PathKeyCA} -CAcreateserial -out {Domain}.crt -days 825 -sha256 -extfile {Domain}.ext
```

Code:

```
 Process cmd = new Process();

 cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
 cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
 cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

 cmd.Start();

 using (StreamWriter sw = cmd.StandardInput) {

     if (sw.BaseStream.CanWrite) {
         foreach (Models.Command command in commands) {

             try {

                 if (!command.Prompt) {
                     // Command execution
                     sw.WriteLine(command.Descripcion);
                 } else {
                     // Input prompt
                     cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine(command.Descripcion);
                     cmd.StandardInput.Flush();
                 }
             } catch (Exception ex2) {


             }
         }
     }
 }
            
 cmd.Close();
```

Comment: Any exception catched?

Comment: Nope, it just writes the line without submit